# What does complex content with mixed="true" allow in XML Schema?

Tags: xsd

I have the following definitions in the XML Schema:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="ExpressionType" abstract="true"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="PropertyNameType">
    <xsd:complexContent mixed="true">
      <xsd:extension base="ogc:ExpressionType"/>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

What does the `PropertyNameType` actually allow as content? Just textual content or is there more to it?

`PropertyNameType` is a complex type with complex content and `mixed="true"`, extending another empty abstract complex type. That's all. My question is, which content it may have.

It may clearly have textual content (because of `mixed="true"`). But is something else allowed? Or is there some extension method which would put more stuff in, something with substitution groups perhaps?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm not quite sure, what you mean. My question is, what may the allowed content for `PropertyNameType` be. Doesn't that identify what I'm trying to clarify?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It looks that I fail to communicate the problem properly. `PropertyNameType` is a complex type with complex content and `mixed="true"`, extending another empty abstract complex type. That's all. My question is, which content it may have. Clearly textual content is allowed - but is something else allowed? Or is there some extension method which would put more stuff in, something with substitution groups perhaps?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Side notes: no, w3schools does not explain it and the question you linked to is not really relevant.

Comment: In that case, I completely failed to comprehend your question. Sorry. Deleting irrelevant comments now...

Comment: @AndrewMorton No problem, you helped to form the question properly, I am grateful for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: No, only textual content is allowed.

So if the element `test` is defined as:

```
<xs:element name="test" type="PropertyNameType" />
```

Then the only valid content is:

```
<test>Hello World!</test>
```

No attributes, no child elements.